# plone.app.multilingual: Access Translated Object's Attributes

Tags: plone

Environment: Plone 4.3.3, plone.app.multilingual 2.0a4 (checkout from github), in my case, two languages (en and zh) are enabled, ie a bilingual site.

My [custom Dexterity type](https://github.com/l34marr/cckf.content/blob/master/cckf/content/models/sinology.xml#L10) has a field `remoteUrl`, its definition looks like this:

```
<field name="remoteUrl"
 type="zope.schema.TextLine">
  <title i18n:translate="">URL</title>
  <description i18n:translate="">Link to the Resource.</description>
  <default>http://</default>
  <required>False</required>
</field>
```

My scenario is like this: When creating the item in the zh folder (zh/my_item), the `remoteUrl` field is filled, it will be displayed according to [the template](https://github.com/l34marr/cckf.content/blob/master/cckf/content/browser/sinology.pt#L18). Then, when translating the item into en language (en/my_item), I want it display the value from zh/my_item if the `remoteUrl` field unfilled in en/my_item. On the other hand, if filled in en/my_item, its value will be used and displayed for the `remoteUrl` field.

The existing **[Language Independent Field](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual#language-independent-fields)** does not meet my needs, because the filled value will affect both zh/en items. How do I access zh/my_item `remoteUrl` value from en/my_item context? Any hints or sample snippets for the view class / template will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to display an alternative value from the other language, you can access translations from catalog index TranslationGroup. Just an idea.